# How to define helper method in concerns of controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I have a `ColumnSort` module in my rails project.

```
module ColumnSort
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def sort_column
    # do something
  end
end
```

And I'm using it from `CompaniesController` and `UsersController`.

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  include ColumnSort
  helper_method :sort_column
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include ColumnSort
  helper_method :sort_column
end
```

It works fine. But I want to write the line `helper_method :sort_column` in the module `ColumnSort`. How can I write it?

Answer (score -3):

You don't have to call the helper_method. helper_method is to expose a controller method to the view not to import methods from a helper class.

```
include ColumnSort
```

This line, includes already all methods contained within the Helper Class.

You can read more about it in the Rails API docs: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method

Comment: I want to use the method from view.

Comment: Why don't you define both the include and helper_method once in the application controller ? You can skip adding it in every controller.

Comment: Because I only use the method in these two controllers and views. There are other controllers and views working without the `sort_column` method.